# Unix Create directory based on first value in file, then copy file from the full path listed in the same file to the directory

Tags: unix

I have the following file containing a value before the '|' (I can change the delimiter if needed). I want to create two directories 368126 and 368153 (these values can change), and then copy the files that are in listed after the '|' from their full path location to the directories 368126 and 368153. How can I do this? Any help greatly appreciated.

368126|/nfs/filesEU/UA08039_512.png

368126|/nfs/filesEU/UA08039_256.png

368153|/nfs/filesUS/UA06495_512.png

368153|/nfs/filesUS/UA06495_256.png

368153|/nfs/filesUS/UA06495_64.png

I want to end up with the files sitting in the new directories like this

368126

```
UA08039_512.png
UA08039_256.png
```

368153

```
UA06495_512.png
UA06495_256.png
UA06495_64.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to generate the script to be executed for the movement:

```
awk -F\| '{print "mkdir -p " $1 " ; cp " $2 " " $1}' input_file > script.sh
```

The execute the script as

```
sh ./script.sh
```

Not very efficient but hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks very much, that does the job! I have a few thousand images to copy and will test shortly.

Comment: If I put this command in a shell script how could I use parameters for the path of the input_file and script.sh (I would like to put them in the same location). I'm not good with awk, but I know how to use parameters usually like ./script.sh "/nfs/files/output"

Comment: If you replace input_file with $1 and put that line in the script, you can pass the file as command line argument. This is pretty basic and should be known already.